# How can I use service in resolver? [NESTJS]

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a problem, that in `Resolver` my `Service` is `undefined`.

Check my code:

- module where I use the service:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

- module where I want to reuse my service:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AuthResolver } from './auth.resolver';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/users/users.module';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule],
  providers: [AuthResolver],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

- resolver where I want use the service:

```
import { Args, Query, Mutation, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { User, UsersService } from 'src/users';

Resolver(() => User);
export class AuthResolver {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    console.log(this.usersService);
  }

  @Query(() => String)
  getUser() {
    return 'first_string';
  }

  @Mutation(() => String)
  signUp(@Args('email') email: string, @Args('password') password: string) {
    return this.usersService.create(email, password);
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help)

Comment: Did you try adding `UsersService` to providers in your `AuthModule`?

Comment: @Enslev why I need to do that? But anyway if I add it, problem still there =(

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4163

I just need `@` sign before Resolver.